# Why is a singular matrix rare?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, intuition

I am exploring patterns of integers in $n\times n$ matrices.  I have two matrices that have a determinant of $0$ and a circulant matrix that has positive determinants that differ depending on $n$.

I snipped this from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_matrix) and bolded the important part:

---

A square matrix that is not invertible is called singular or degenerate.
**A square matrix is singular if and only if its determinant is 0. Singular
matrices are rare** in the sense that if you pick a random square matrix
over a continuous uniform distribution on its entries, it will almost
surely not be singular.

---

The Good:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
The Bad:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
And the Ugly:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\
 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 \\
 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 \\
 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The Good is same as Ugly mod n and both are singular.
The Bad is the circulant Good and has determinant $>0$.

Two questions:

1. What makes a singular matrix rare?
2. Has anyone documented the differences? (preferably, using $n$ or $n^2$)

Comment: Hint: construct equivalence classes of matrices determined by their determinant. You'll see that singular matrices are comparatively small (i.e., represented by a single class) out of uncountably many equivalence classes (assuming you are working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$)...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the $n^{\rm th}$ column elements[...] are always multiples of $n.$" E.g., $(a,b;a,b)\in\operatorname{Mat}_{2\times 2}$ is singular for any choice of $a,b.$

Comment: What does "Each row is well-ordered up to a multiple of five" mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, post has been updated.

Comment: Your observations only apply because you're looking at these special kinds of matrices. If you have $n>3$, decreasing the entries of the "Ugly" matrix by 1 will still keep it singular, and you can obviously shuffle up the columns without changing the determinant.

Comment: @ronno, that's what I want to find out.  Has anyone examined this type of scenario?

Comment: So, now it says, "each row is well-ordered up to a multiple of $n$," thereby raising my not-understanding to a new level.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, these are the singular matrices, Good and Ugly.

Comment: Nope, no closer to understanding what you mean by "well-ordered up to a multiple of $n$," but very close to concluding that you don't understand what you mean by that phrase, either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thinking in terms of probability helps. If you have a continuous probability distribution defined on some space of matrices, then typically the singular matrices will have probability zero. Thinking in terms of the determinant: The determinant is a polynomial in the entries of the matrix. Setting it to zero gives a polynomial equation, which are defining (implicitely) some surface in the matrix space. This surface will have a reduced dimension , so its (Lebesgue) measure will be zero.

Answer (score 12):

The number of $2\times2$ matrices over a field of $q$ elements is $q^4$.

The number of non-singular $2\times2$ matrices over a field of $q$ elements is $$(q^2-1)(q^2-q)=q^4-q^3-q^2+q$$ which means only $q^3+q^2-q$ out of $q^4$ are singular.

Comment: I've failed to figure out how the number of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field of $q$ elements is computed. Could you give or indicate a proof?

Comment: @jobe, you have four slots to fill, each of which can be filled in $q$ ways, hence, $q^4$.

Comment: Sorry, I've mistakenly forgotten the word *non-singular*. I am interested in the number of non-singular matrices.

Comment: The top row can be anything but $(0,0)$, so $q^2-1$ choices. The other row can be anything but a scalar multiple of the top row, so $q^2-q$ choices.

Comment: Forgot to include @jobe in previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extension of Gerry's argument.  There are $q^{n^2}$ matrices in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ and $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^k)$ elements in $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

$$\lim_{q\to\infty}\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^k)}{q^{n^2}}=\lim_{q\to\infty}(q^{-n};q)_n=\lim_{q\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-q^{-n+k}\right)=1$$ where $(q^{-n};q)_n$ is the [$q$-Pochammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html).

Note that the fact that $\mathbb{F}_q$ has nonzero characteristic doesn't affect this argument, since the formula $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^k)$ is based on picking $n$ linearly independent vectors combinatorially from $(\mathbb{F}_q)^n$, a process which extends to the infinite case independently of characteristic.

Comment: Good has rank 1 and Ugly has rank 2.  Bad has no rank. I'm new at this stuff, so I hope I've read it right.

Answer (score 3):

If you think about the interpretation of a matrix as a system of equations, and take the 2-variable case as an easy to visualize example, most pairs of equations are not parallel lines.  If the 2nd column is a multiple of the first, then they are parallel. Inb this case, the 2nd column will be a multiple of the first.

Of course, for the 3 dimensional case, there are linear combinations, so this no longer holds in the same sense, but you still have the nth column as a "multiple" of one or both of the other columns.

Does that clarify, or is there something more complex you are noticing?

Answer (score 3):

There's at least one very easy way to think about this. Imagine the $n$ column vectors as just points in $\mathbf{R}^n$. Now the matrix is singular if and only if these points all lie in a single $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace i.e hyperplane that goes through the origin. Typically if I just pick $n$ random points, there is basically no chance they will accidentally lie on a single hyperplane.