# For a class of matrices $M_{2n}$: $\dim(\ker(M_{2n}))$ is zero if $n$ is even and 2 if $n$ is odd

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let us consider the class of matrices of the following form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&A\\B&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ nonsingular real antisymmetric matrices. After some numerical experiments I noticed that for $n$ even the null space is trivial, but for $n$ odd the null space has dimension 2. I was unable to prove or disprove that, so I am asking this question in the hope that someone else could do it.

EDIT: [Any odd dimensional antisymmetric matrix is singular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287709/prove-that-determinant-of-an-odd-dimension-anti-symmetric-matrix-is-zero), so the null space has dimension at least one for theses matrices and that is the origin for the 2-dimensional null space I was seeing: one dimension for $A$ and other
for $B$.

EDIT2: I was performing my numerical experiments with random matrices, so I did not worry about the matrices been singular because I knew that [singular matrices are rare](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255101/why-is-a-singular-matrix-rare), then a systematic generation of singular matrices was basically impossible *unless* there is some basic mathematical fact that make them be singular, as it was the case. Anyway, the rank of the odd dimensional antisymmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ generated randomicaly is $n-1$ and not any number. The simple Octave code I was using is the following:

`N=20
for n=3:N
A=rand(n);
A=A-A';
B=rand(n);
B=B-B';
M=[zeros(n),A;B,zeros(n)];
disp([n,2*n-rank(M)])
endfor`

Anyone can test this code [online](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php).

Comment: Can you give an example where you have a non-trivial null-space? I think in that case the matrices have to be singular, at least one of them.

Comment: You are correct. Any odd dimensional antisymmetric matrix is singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant of this matrix [is $(-1)^n \det(A)\det(B)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) (when $n$ is odd you need an odd number of column transpositions to make your matrix block-diagonal), therefore it is not zero since you assumed that the matrices $A$ and $B$ were non-singular. It follows that $M$ can't have a non-trivial nullspace.

Comment: You are right. In fact, any odd dimensional antisymmetric matrix must be singular. Each eigenvector for the zero eigenvalue came from a singular matrix, so the dimension 2 for the null space.

Comment: @jobe It could be more than two as well, right? In the extreme case, the zero matrix is anti-symmetric.

Comment: The matrices were generated randomicaly , so the probability they were systematically singular is zero in practice. That is why I supposed they were nonsingular. I didn't know odd dimensional antisymmetric matrices were singular and ended up discovering in a tortuous way.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is odd, then $A$ and $B$ cannot be nonsingular. Indeed, for $n$ odd and $A$ antisymmetric,
$$
\det(A)=\det(A^T)=\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det(A)=-\det(A)
$$
so $\det(A)=0$ and $A$ is singular.

So if $A$ are to be nonsingular, you conclude $n$ is even and also that
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & A \\ B & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
is nonsingular, because with $n$ row exchanges you can bring the matrix in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & A \end{bmatrix}
$$
and this matrix has determinant $\det(B)\det(A)$, by a repeated application of Laplace expansion.

For $n$ odd you can surely say that the kernel has dimension $2$, but you could as well say the kernel has dimension $42$, because there is *no* matrix of that kind that can falsify $\dim(\ker M)=42$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've made some edits that explain why the rank of the odd dimensional antisymmetric matrices I was using is $n-1$ and why - being ignorant that odd dimensional antisymmetric matrices are singular- I assumed they were not.

Comment: @jobe If you don't assume $A$ and $B$ nonsingular, then the rank of $M$ can be whatever even number between $0$ and $2n$.